# Version control integration with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, mercurial

I'm looking for a version control system just for me on my windows computer to integrate into eclipse. I was thinking to use Mercurial instead of Subversion, but I'm having doubts about the mercurial eclipse plugin. Any input on this that you can help me with?

Is it worth it to have a version control system when you're working alone, how much is it going to complicate matters? I don't think I need a remote repository since it's just for me. And what is known to work well in eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it worth it to have a version control system when you're working alone

Yes of course, you will always run in cases like, the application was running yesterday but i dont know what i did!

> how much is it going to complicate matters?

It will not complicate anything, you will just need to spend half an hour at the beginning to set it, then committing,branching, uploading, sharing will all be one click away in Eclipse.

> I don't think I need a remote repository since it's just for me.

I work alone as well, but you never know, if you might work on different sites it would be good to have all your work in the cloud, sometimes you run in cases like you want to share a project with a friend and whats better than SVN in that case.

> And what is known to work well in eclipse?

I use Subversion, inside Eclipse and TortoiseSVN in the explorer.

If you want to setup your own SVN Server, (with the benefit of not needing to upload/download from internet each time) check here:

- [Create SVN Server on Windows](http://www.codeandcoffee.com/2007/07/how-to-setup-a-subversion-server-on-windows/)
- [Create SVN Server on Mac](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Subversion-on-Mac-OS-X)

Answer (score 7):

Is it worth having a version control system for just yourself ? Absolutely. Why ?

1. You can retrieve old versions of code - for reference, to revert changes.
2. you can branch and tag to create different versions and checkpoint for releases.
3. Your continuous integration system (you do have one, don't you?) can tag successful builds, allowing you to identify particular intermediate builds.
4. You can record in the logs *why* you've changed stuff (as opposed to *what* you've changed), and meta-information surrounding those changes.

So version control isn't used to manage multiple developers, but rather to manage the *codebase* itself.

What works well in Eclipse ? I can vouch for Subversion. I've used that successfully for a couple of years. I'm not sure I'd use a distributed system like Mercurial, unless I was in the habit of (say) developing on a laptop on the move, and on a desktop at home.

Answer (score 3):

I have used the [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) plugin for SVN and it worked like a charm. In regards to whether or not you need a version control system while working alone, it's still a good idea. It will save your version history and allow for easy rollbacks. Also, if you ever bring on another person to the project it will be easy to get them up and going.

Answer (score 2):

It IS important to have a SCM system even when working alone.
I'd suggest creating a project in [code.google.com](http://code.google.com) or [sf.net](http://sf.net), (unless of course you don't want an open source license).

Eclipse has built-in "Local history", you can check if it is sufficient for your needs. Otherwise you can simply install an SVN server from Collab.net, and use it on localhost with [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/)

Answer (score 1):

There is also a git plugin for eclipse. only problem is merge not being integrated yet. but is planned for the near future.

[egit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/)

Answer (score 0):

The [Mercurial plugin](http://www.vectrace.com/mercurialeclipse/) for Eclipse seems to work fine. I don't think it has all of the features that [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) has for Subversion though.

If you are working alone on a project though, you need to ask yourself why you are using a distributed version control system. For a project by yourself, Subversion works great. I use subversion and the eclipse project for projects I work on by myself. It gives you the history and rollback capabilities even with a single person. It is nice sometimes to be able to see what you did before that you might have deleted.

In a team environment though, the Mercurial plugin for Eclipse works fine.